# Is there some bonus for New Year answers?!?

Tags: support, reputation

I've just posted [an answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2587681/212120) to a question. To be precise, the timestamp reads `2018-01-01 15:09:53Z`. Almost at the same time, I was happy to notice I had an upvote in my Achievements icon. The happiness turned into surprise when I noticed that the upvote was on that same answer. The upvote took place around 8 seconds after the post (stamped `2018-01-01 15:10:01Z`).

Is this some kind of New Year prize, or simply just someone working very hard to get an Electorate badge?

Comment: Just somebody who was quick to upvote that answer, for whatever reason.

Comment: @DanielFischer Too quick! Thank you very much

Comment: Although I doubt that that's the case here, sometimes I upvote an answer very fast. That's when I am about to answer and someone else posts the answer that I had in mind. Since I was thinking about it, I can see very fast that it is a correct answer.

Answer (score 4):

There are no bonus votes given out by the site. Some hats are awarded based on the time of posting, but this is something different.

Indeed, sometimes votes happen surprisingly fast. It is not necessarily true that this was a consequence of badge hunting, but we cannot exclude it either.

(Tangentially it'd be better to vote on questions to get an electorate badge.)